# Class diagram code-generators for ANSI-C in Eclipse

Tags: c, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, code-generation

I'd like to graph out my classes (structs) in something UML-like and have the supporting shell code be generated for me in C. Does anything like this exist?  Freeware && Eclipse plugins preferred.

Answer (score 1):

[Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) use the dot tool to build graphs

[yEd](http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yed_about.html) is a good graph renderer tool

[Zest](http://www.eclipse.org/gef/zest/) is a good toolbox for drawing graph

If your header (*.h) files are well written you may parse them with xText and a subset of C grammar to drive yEd, zest or dot.